# T-SQL join table in where exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below query

```
select * 
from monthly_accounts m
join blocks_Dep on (m.code = d.code )
where exists (select R_code 
              from balance c 
              inner join blocks_div d on (m.b_id = d.b_id and c.name = d.name)
             )
```

I am getting an error about an invalid `m.b_i` identifier; how to make join between the first table and tables in exists with the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are getting that error because the operator is `exists` not `exist`.  Does this work?

```
select m.*, d.*
from monthly_accounts m join
     blocks_Dep d
     on m.code = d.code
where exists (select 1
              from balance b inner join
                   blocks_div bd
                   on b.name = bd.name
              where m.b_id = bd.b_id
             );
```

Note that I made other changes and fixed other problems:

- `blocks_dep` did not have a table alias.
- I assigned table aliases that are *abbreviations* of the table names for all tables.
- I moved the correlation clause to a `where` rather than the `on`.  I don't expect to see correlation clauses in an `on` (although the logic is correct).

Comment: its `exists`  typo mistake , well i dont think it will resolve howerver ill rety again , and ill try a sql fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You have some answers

The core should stand on it's own
Use alias and don't repeat the alias

```
select * from 
monthly_accounts m
join blocks_Dep on (m.code=d.code)
```

d is not yet defined. Even the query parser figured it out I doubt that is what you wanted.

This links the not exists by `m.b_id` which is what I think you mean to do?

```
select * 
from monthly_accounts m
join blocks_Dep d1
      on m.code = d1.code 
where not exists ( select 1 
                   from balance c 
                   join blocks_div d2  
                     on d2.b_id = m.b_id  
                    and d2.name = c.name 
                 )
```